# How can I do y-axes with chart.js

Tags: charts, chart.js

How can I do y-axes with chart.js

[image]

Comment: No API for this. Anyway add code example.

Comment: can I do this by other libraries?

Comment: Look like no so useful idea i am not sure. You use dynamic data? Maybe put absolute div next to the chart